# The equation of straight line through two points from tuple and output max values

Tags: python

i have tuples in a list :

```
a = [((1, 6), (8, 2)), ((8, 2), (6, 3)), ((6, 3),(9,4))]
```

i want to use "for" to assign all value in list, example:

```
P = [1,6], Q = [8,2] => perform find a straight line, then
P = [8,2], Q = [6,3] => perform find a straight line, then
P = [6,3], Q = [9,4] => perform find a straight line, then
```

output in the screen :

```
PQ1 : y = b1x+c1
PQ2 : y = b2x+c2
```

max values d

but i have error:

> 'float' object is not iterable

I don't know how to use " for ", "function" and "class" for this situation

```
def function(P,Q):
   a = float(P[0]-Q[0])
   b = float(Q[1]-P[1])
   c = float((b*P[0]+a*P[1]))
   d = b/(-a)
   e = (-c)/(-a)
   if d == 0.0 and e == 0.0:
      print("False")
   elif d == 0.0:
      print("Function is y = ",e)
   elif d == 1.0 and e == 0.0:
      print("Function is y = x")
   elif d != 1.0 and e == 0.0:
      print("Function is y = ",d,"x")
   elif d == 1.0 and e > 0:
      print("Function is y = x + ",e)
   elif d == 1.0 and e < 0:
      print("Function is y = x ",e)
   elif e > 0:
      print("Function is y =",d,"x +",e)
   elif e < 0:
      print("Function is y =",d,"x",e)
if __name__ == '__main__': 
   P = [1,6]
   Q = [8,2]
   function(P,Q)
```

I want to use " for ", "function" and "class" instead of assigning each value to P and Q by hand, because tuple can extend more

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
for P, Q in a:
    function(P, Q)
```

**Why it works?**

```
  a = [((1, 6), (8, 2)), ((8, 2), (6, 3)), ((6, 3),(9,4))]
```

If you'll iterate over `a` with single variable, you'll get list element into this variable every iteration. If you provide 2 variables into for loop, python will try to **unpack** list element and, if element is iterable and *count of its elements equals amount of variables you provided*, it'll put values into variables in same order.

Demonstration code:

```
a, b, c, d = (1, 2, 3, 4)  # working
print(a, b, c, d)
a, b, c, d = [1, 2, 3, 4]  # working
print(a, b, c, d)
a, b, c, d = {1, 2, 3, 4}  # working
print(a, b, c, d)
a, b, c, d = "1234"        # working
print(a, b, c, d)
a, b, c, d = range(1, 5)   # working
print(a, b, c, d)
a, b, c, d = (1, 2)        # error
```

Comment: can you write details ?

Comment: @vũtuấnđức, any questions?

Comment: how to output max  values d ?

Comment: @vũtuấnđức, I don't know what is `d`, but take a look on [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).